# Access denied when Importing a Sharepoint list

Tags: list, export, import, access-denied

I have a serious problem when importing a Sharepoint List exported from a test server.
During import, the log file encounter many problems of right access like

```
Debug: Security check failed in OnUserGroupExport
```

or

```
Debug: Security check failed in OnFolderImport
```

or again

```
[File] [AllItems.aspx]   Warning: Access denied.
```

I looked on this post http://www.fixkar.com/articles/kb/1150/ and changed my site collection administrator but it didn't change anything in the log file...
If you have a piece of clue it will be so great !

Thank you by advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: which user did you use to import the list?

Comment: I used the Administrator PowerShell with the Import-SPWeb command on the SP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you ran the Powershell shell run as Administrator, what happened if you specified the -force parameter? Did anything in the target list get created?

Comment: I just came back to work and see that this list was correctly imported. I don't if it's a kind of miracle and I apology because I came back with no solution, but it works for me... Thank you !